# How to replace NA values with different values based on column in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am trying to replace NA values by column with values predetermined from a vector. For example, I have vector containing the values (1,5,3) and a dataframe df, and want to replace all NA values from column one of df with 1, column two NA's with 5, and column three NA's with 3.

I tried a formula I saw that took

```
df[is.na(df)] = vector
```

but didn't seem to work due to "wrong length". Both the vector and #columns in df are also the same length.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to replace the corresponding columns in the dataset with the value in the vector and replace it directly and this would almost all the time and it is a single step replacement and is concise

```
df[] <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, is.na(x), y), df, vec)
df
#  col1 col2 col3
#1    1    5    2
#2    3    2    3
#3    1    5    3
```

---

Or another option is to make the lengths same, and then use `pmax`

```
df[] <- pmax(as.matrix(df), is.na(df) * vec[col(df)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

or another option with `replace`

```
df <- replace(df, is.na(df), rep(vec, colSums(is.na(df))))
```

NOTE: All the solutions above are one-liner

---

Or using `data.table` with `set`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
for(j in seq_along(df)) set(df, i = which(is.na(df[[j]])), j = j, value = vec[j])
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 3, NA), col2 = c(NA, 2, NA), col3 = c(2, NA, NA))
vec <- c(1, 5, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` to get row/column index of `NA` values and replace it directly.

```
mat <- which(is.na(df), arr.ind = TRUE)
df[mat] <- vector[mat[, 2]]
```